# Create a F# class with a sequence property

Tags: f#

Here's the code:

```
type Advertisement() =
    member val Photos = seq<images> with get,set
```

but this returns a function signature for the property Photos as

```
seq<images> -> seq<images>
```

I just want the property to represent a sequence of images

```
seq<images>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You're supplying `seq<images>` where a value is expected. Did you mean `member val Photos = Seq.empty<images> with get,set`?

Comment: OK that makes sense. So seq<images> is the type and Seq.empty<images> is the value.

Comment: Can you explain this in an answer so that I may mark it as my solution.

Comment: Oh wow, it took me like 15 minutes to understand what `seq<images>` means when used as an expression. It is colored like a keyword or builder, but actually referring to the function `Operators.seq<'T>`, not the `seq` builder, which isn't a builder but a compiler hack for performance... but the function is documented with stuff concerning the builder-like-thing? Good gracious, where did the principle of least astonishment go?

Comment: @user1206480 : It looks to me that Vandroiy has better information for a proper answer than I do. ;-]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is that you want to use `seq<images>` as a *type annotation*, but you're using it as an *expression*. These have different meanings; also, it's not clear what sequence you want to assign to `Photos`.

For example, if you want to initialize `Photos` to an empty sequence, you could use `Seq.empty` and have `seq<images>` as a type annotation:

```
    member val Photos = Seq.empty : seq<images> with get, set
```

Or, as ildjarn suggested, use an explicit type parameter for `Seq.empty<'T>`:

```
    member val Photos = Seq.empty<images> with get, set
```

If the type of `Photos` is clear from its usage in the same code file, the compiler will infer the type and you can even shorten it to:

```
    member val Photos = Seq.empty with get, set
```

### Why did the original code return a fuction?

When you wrote `seq<images>` where an expression, not a type is expected (i.e. not behind a `:` or as a type parameter), the compiler resolved it to [`Operators.seq<'T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/operators.seq%5B't%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D), which is the function of signature `seq<images> -> seq<images>` you are getting.

The implementation of `seq` is a little weird; it is supposed to behave like a [computation expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/computation-expressions) but is actually a special case for the compiler. It is used both to cast to `seq<'T>` via the function you've seen, and to signify [sequence expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/sequences), as in `seq { yield 1 }`.

Answer (score 3):

`seq<images>` is referring to the `seq` builder, like the one that you use in the following way

```
let foo = seq { yield "bar" }
```

You can actually see this if you hit <kbd>F12</kbd> on `seq`. To instantiate an empty sequence you need to use `Seq.empty<images>`.